# Android app still running after delete

Tags: android

I started developing an android app and installed it unsigned on my nexus one. Now I removed the apk file and rebooted the N1. But the app is still running... How do I completely remove this app now? Regards Andrea

Comment: If you uninstalled the app, the app is not running. I suspect that you simply did not successfully uninstall the app, for whatever reason.

Comment: No I didn't uninstall it because I could not find the app in the installed apps neither in the running apps... found the apk file and removed it

Comment: There is no normal way of installing the app that would cause it to not show up in the list of applications in Settings. Furthermore, unsigned apps cannot run on an Android device.

Comment: I looked everywhere and cannot find it.
The file name was name-debug.apk and I'm sure it was unsigned.

Comment: `name-debug.apk` is signed, with the debug signing key. "I looked everywhere and cannot find it" -- how did you install it?

Comment: I didn't know for the debug signing key... I uploaded the file to gdrive and on the N1 I installed the app from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find your app in the list in manage applications section in Settings -> Applications. If you can't find it by its name, check the package name you used. And note that the list might not be on alphabetical order, use the context menu for ordering them. When you open your app from the list, you find the uninstall button there.

Comment: Which version of Android are you running?

Comment: 2.3.6 is the android version

Comment: I looked everywhere and I cannot find it... it's driving me crazy... I followed your update...

Comment: How do you then know it's running?

Comment: You can try to uninstall it from the command line using the [adb tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). `adb uninstall com.foo.bar` (replace with the package name you used)

Comment: I know it is running because the app listen to incoming sms and show a toast message...

Comment: You could try connecting your phone to your computer via USB cable and then using adb to uninstall it. Or maybe you could try to install it again and see if you can then find it from the manage applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you’ve installed an app on your phone or tablet using Google Play that you no longer want, you can uninstall it by following these steps:

1. Navigate to Menu > Settings > Applications > Manage applications (on devices running Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich, Settings > Apps).
2. Scroll through the list of apps to find the one you’d like to uninstall.
3. Tap on the app you’d like to uninstall.
4. Tap “Uninstall.”

Comment: I installed it over gdrive... no google play. It's still e test